# GeoDjango admin: show PointField on a map?

Tags: django, django-admin, geodjango

I have a PointField (`position`) in my Django model. I would like to display it as a read-only map in my Django admin interface. However, whenever I set it to be read-only, it's displaying as text.

This is my definition in admin.py:

```
class PostcodeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('postcode', 'position', )
    fields = ['postcode', 'position']
    readonly_fields = ['postcode', 'position']
```

Whenever I remove it from the list of read-only fields, it displays on a map: whenever I set it to be read-only, it displays as text.

Is it possible to have it is a read-only map? I'm using Django 1.7.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields), ```Any fields in this option will display its data as-is and non-editable```. The ```readonly_fields``` attribute seems not to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `modifiable` [attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/admin/#django.contrib.gis.admin.GeoModelAdmin.modifiable).

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin

class PostcodeAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    modifiable = False
```

Comment: hey, I know your answer is almost 10 years old but I just posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78206490/readonly-map-for-geodjango-fields-in-django-4-0) on how to achieve this in more recent Django versions (>= 4.0) where the OSMGeoAdmin class has been deprecated, in case you have any advice.