# Readonly map for GeoDjango fields in Django>=4.0?

Tags: django, django-admin, geodjango

I was searching old answers on how to **show the dynamic Openlayers map but not allow you to move/change the coordinates/geometry of a given GeoDjango field** (a PointField in my case) in the Django Admin.

[Old solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350332/geodjango-admin-show-pointfield-on-a-map) mention using the `OSMGeoAdmin` class (`from django.contrib.gis.admin`), which allows you to set the `modifiable` attribute to `False` to make the map be shown but not modifiable. This is exactly what I want.

However, that class is deprecated since Django 4.0, and you are now prompted to use `ModelAdmin` or `GISModelAdmin` instead, but none of the two allow me to replicate the same behaviour as `OSMGeoAdmin`.

I checked [the documentation for GISModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/gis/forms-api/#django.contrib.gis.forms.widgets.OSMWidget) and I found out that I can send some parameters to the `gis_widget` using the dictionary `gis_widget_kwargs`, but the modifiable attribute is still not working, so I am beggining to think that the functionality was removed.

Example of code to pass parameters to the `gis_widget`:

```
@admin.register(m.City)
class CityAdmin(GISModelAdmin):
    gis_widget_kwargs = {'attrs':{'map_width':1200, 'modifiable':False}}
```

Am I missing something? Is that really no longer possible with `GISModelAdmin`?
Do I have to go through the annoying process of creating my own widget to replicate this behaviour?

If someone has faced the same situation, did you manage to find a workaround?